# threading in web application giving a session timed out when hosted on iis 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In my asp.net application, iam using windows forms.dll to use some of the windows controls by creating a thread.This works fine in my system but is giving a session timeout when hosted on IIS.
Creating a thread gives me session time out on IIS. 
How do i create threads that can work fine on IIS?

Below is the code where iam created the thread.

```
public string[] DisplayFileDialog()
    {
        string[] result = null;

        try
        {
            Thread objThread = new Thread(state =>{
                result = FnOpenFileDialog();
                // TODO: do something with the returned result
            });

            objThread.IsBackground = false;
            objThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            objThread.Start();
            objThread.Join();
            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            return result;
        }

 protected string[] FnOpenFileDialog()
    {
        IntPtr hdlr = GetForegroundWindow();

        WindowWrapper Mockwindow = new WindowWrapper(hdlr);

        OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        fDialog.Title = "Select Files";

        fDialog.Multiselect = true;
        fDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        fDialog.CheckPathExists = true;

        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = fDialog.ShowDialog(Mockwindow);
        string[] filenames = fDialog.FileNames;
        return filenames;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executed server side, which is why your stalled by a time out response. Your main thread waits (objThread.Join) for the response of a dialog box opened on the server as you can't see it on the client side you never get a response.

If you want to open the dialog file on the client side you can do it in a similar way as was ActiveX objects.

You can find a msdn tutorial of how to do it at the following address but it only work in IE:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/magazine/cc301932(en-us).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/magazine/cc301932%28en-us%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Iam using the windows forms file dialog control as my requirement is to be able to select multiple files in IE7. I cannot use other upload controls like ajax as that are not working on IE 7 and lower versions.

Comment: I have referred your link.Iam new to active x object creation.Iam stuck in creating windows control library.Could you help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the answer is simply: You can't do that.

Windows forms controls don't work in a browser. It works on your machine because the browser window is local, so the thread can attach to it and use it as a parent.

The IIS process doesn't have a window, it only serves up text, images, and video files. You're essentially asking an IIS thread, running on some machine in a server room somewhere else, to connect to a browser's window on someone else's machine, and then start displaying Windows Forms controls on it.

What if they are on a Linux box, or a Mac?

ASP.NET was created to solve this problem of creating interactive forms for IIS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.I get that windows form control cannot attach to web.To resolve, i am creating a mock window and assigning it as parent to the control.This lines in code does it.                                                                 IntPtr hdlr = GetForegroundWindow();  -- here iam getting handler of current browser.              WindowWrapper Mockwindow = new WindowWrapper(hdlr); --here iam creating a mock window for that handler and  assiging that mock window as parent to form control.                   System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = fDialog.ShowDialog(Mockwindow);

Comment: It's not going to work. Your web server (IIS in this case) cannot send a graphic representation of the Windows Form  Control across the wire to the browser. The web doesn't work like that. You need to create HTML, CSS, and possibly some Javascript to send over the wire. ASP.NET has some really nice .NET server controls that do all the work for you - for example asp:Button will generate all the HTML needed to show a button on the web page, along with all the code needed to link it back to your server code ("OnClick" handler) when someone clicks it.